# Can't access resources folder in Java

Tags: java, gradle, resources, classpath, classloader

I tried to access resources (marked as) folder in Java app but nothing works, returns wrong paths

I've tried:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
System.out.println(classLoader.getResource("."));
```

and

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Config.class.getClassLoader();
System.out.println(classLoader.getResource("."));
```

but it shows me
`file:/D:/testProject/build/classes/main/`, and of course there's no resource files :(

How to access exactly `resources` folder?

```
-TestProject
 |-resources
 |-src
   |-main
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be aware that the word *resource* in your Gradle structure and the word *resource* in `ClassLoader` are unrelated.

As your `ClassLoader` might have more than one root, you need to loop over the roots. Use `getResources()` instead of `getResource()`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-

Like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Config.class.getClassLoader();
// or use:
// ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
// depending on what's appropriate in your case.
Enumeration<URL> roots = classLoader.getResources(".");
while (roots.hasMoreElements()) {
    final URL url = roots.nextElement();
    System.out.println(url);
}
```